# hive: NoMatchingMethodException No matching method for class

Tags: java, hadoop, hive, user-defined-functions, bigdata

I have created a UDAF in the hive which will return the first repeating number in the column.

Table: firstrepeatingnumber, Column: indata, data:

```
55
125
1561234
123
12
1
-123
321
124
55
123
15236
32
125
44
```

UDAF: practise.FirstRepeatingNumber

UDAF:

```
package practise;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.UDAF;
import org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.UDAFEvaluator;
@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
public class FirstRepeatingNumber extends UDAF{
    class firstRepeatingNumberUDAFEvaluator implements UDAFEvaluator{
        int len=0,number=0,index=0,i=0,j=0,arrLength=0,set=0,ans=0;
        ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> arr = new ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>>();
        ArrayList<Integer> arr2 = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        @Override
        public void init() {
            for(i=0;i<10;i++)
                arr.add(new ArrayList<Integer>());
        }
        public boolean iterate(int value){
            if(set==1)
                return true;
            index=value%10;
            try{arrLength=arr.get(index).size();}
            catch(Exception ex){}
            for(j=0;j<arrLength;j++){
                if(value==arr.get(index).get(j)){
                    ans=value;
                    set=1;
                    return true;
                }
            }
            if(set==0)
            {
                try{
                    arr2=arr.get(index);
                }
                catch(Exception ex){
                }
                arr2.add(value);
                arr.set(index, arr2);
            }
            return true;
        }
        public int terminate(){
            return ans;
        }
    }
}
```

Here is function creation:

```
create function GetFirstReNumber AS 'practise.FirstRepeatingNumber';
```

When I run select query:

```
select GetFirstReNumber(indata) as ans from firstrepeatingnumber;
```

it give error:

> FAILED: **NoMatchingMethodException** No matching method for class practise.FirstRepeatingNumber with (int). Possible choices:

For this UDAF the expected answer is 55 on this dataset. I am unable to understand why is it giving error while executing the function.

Answer (score -1):

You should check the data type of column "indata", which should be `int`.
 And it is strange that I don't see the implementation of function `terminatePartial()` and `merge()`

Answer (score -1):

Please follow below steps:

1.Restart hive

2.DROP FUNCTION xxx

3.CREATE FUNCTION XXX

4.run...